# ChromeDriver error: java.lang.IllegalStateException on mac

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, illegalstateexception

**below the error, I am so confused I tried in different ways and my OS is mac**

```
current dir = /Users/rafa/eclipse-workspace/FirstSelenium_2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/rafa/eclipse-workspace/FirstSelenium_2/‪‪/Users/rafa/eclipse-workspace/FirstSelenium_2/src/chromedriver‬‬
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:14)
```

the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

 String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 System.out.println("current dir = " + dir);


//to open browser
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","‪‪/Users/rafa/eclipse-workspace/FirstSelenium_2/src/chromedriver‬‬");
WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver();
String actualurl="https://www.mycontactform.com";
//open url
d.get(actualurl);
//printing the title of page
String title=d.getTitle();
System.out.println(title);
//printing the actual url
System.out.println("actual url: "+actualurl);
//printing the current  url
System.out.println("current url: "+d.getCurrentUrl());
//maximize the window
d.manage().window().maximize();
  }
```

I have the driver in the dir but still, have this error

Comment: because I did everything in right way and there is a driver and still have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","‪‪/Users/rafa/eclipse-workspace/FirstSelenium_2/src/chromedriver‬‬");
```

With:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","‪‪/src/chromedriver‬‬");
```